# Why does Scalaz use complex symbols and no in-code documentation?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm sometimes looking at Scalaz and find it pretty hard to understand for a beginner Scala programmer.

```
  implicit def KleisliCategory[M[_]: Monad]: Category[({type λ[α, β]=Kleisli[M, α, β]})#λ] = new Category[({type λ[α, β]=Kleisli[M, α, β]})#λ] {
    def id[A] = ☆(_ η)
    def compose[X, Y, Z](f: Kleisli[M, Y, Z], g: Kleisli[M, X, Y]) = f <=< g
  }

  implicit def CokleisliCategory[M[_]: Comonad]: Category[({type λ[α, β]=Cokleisli[M, α, β]})#λ] = new Category[({type λ[α, β]=Cokleisli[M, α, β]})#λ] {
    def id[A] = ★(_ copure)
    def compose[X, Y, Z](f: Cokleisli[M, Y, Z], g: Cokleisli[M, X, Y]) = f =<= g 
  }
```

Scalaz methods may seem obvious for experienced functional programmers, but for anyone else it's hard to understand.

Why is there so few documentation in Scalaz code?

Why do they use so many operators that are unreadable for most people? 
I don't even know how to type `★` or `☆` without copy/pasting. And it's just an example because there are many.

Some people say that Scalaz was unreadable at the beginning, but 2 years later they find it great.
I wonder where to start with Scalaz. The Scala validation seems the easiest part, but after that?

Comment: As far as I know, most special symbols has a verbose, non-unicode companion. Scalaz mimics Haskell and many of that symbols comes from Haskell land (so the next question is [*why Haskell uses so many symbols*](http://ro-che.info/ccc/15.html)). And personally I don't think that *beginner* scala programmer should use scalaz.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I understand. I say I'm a Scala beginner, it's my point of view, but I'm following Martin Odersky courses on Coursera, reading the book, and using it for 3 months now, to build a real world webapp that will soon be in production. I just wonder when should I try to use/understand Scalaz, because until I don't understand it, I'll keep considering myself a Scala beginner :)

Comment: scalaz is on the same level as shapeless and probably the next time there will be a library for exhaustive macro programming in Scala. All of these parts have together, that they are not part of the user core of Scala - they are experiments to proof what is possible and how to abstract to new levels. One is allowed to say that he/she is an advanced Scala programmer without being able to understand the higher order parts of Scala - that's also what Odersky said in his [Scala levels](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8610).

Comment: Nevertheless, learning Scala needs far more time than learning an imperative language - if one does not have experience in another functional language yet. I for my share think that I achieved the advanced Scala programmer level after 9 or 10 months (and working several hours per day with Scala) - but I hadn't any experience with functional programming before.

Comment: @om-nom-nom There may be verbose companions for symbols, but when code is using the symbols, what good is that. I wasn't born with a scalaz symbol to name mapping. How do you go from looking a symbol to figuring out what it's supposed to do? I've found cloning the repo and applying a grep helps a little.

Comment: @BjornTipling that's a good point. Unfortunately I have not found any better way to archive this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree that Scalaz is mostly undocumented. The problem is that it collects a lot of advanced concepts from Haskell (and the underlying mathematics) and documenting them all in detail would become writing a whole book about functional programming (and mathematics). So I believe Scalaz's approach is:

- If you know and need some concept from functional programming prepared for Scala, you'll most likely find it here.
- If you don't know it, you'll have to learn it elsewhere.

Let's have a look at your example: If you know [Kleisli categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category) and how every monads gives rise to one, the definition is quite self-contained. If you don't, then `KleisliCategory` has no use for you anyway.

<sup>(In my experience, Haskell is better for learning advanced concepts from functional programming. While Scala is far better than Java, it still drags around Java's OO/imperative heritage that clutters things a bit.)</sup>

---

Considering the Unicode symbols. Looking at sources it seems that they're used only as a syntactic sugar or at least they have a non-Unicode counterpart:

```
def ☆[M[_], A, B](f: A => M[B]): Kleisli[M, A, B] = kleisli(f)
def η[F[_]](implicit p: Pure[F]): F[A] = pure
def cokleisli[W[_], A, B](f: W[A] => B): Cokleisli[W, A, B] = ★(f)
```

So you can go without them, if you want.

Still, I'm not sure if having them in Scalaz is a good idea. It could make the code impossible to read for someone who lacks the proper fonts. I'd rather prefer pure ASCII symbols.

Answer (score 7):

A place to start is to read Learn You a Haskell which covers many concepts.

Watch Chris Marshall's (@oxbow_lakes) scalaz talks: http://skillsmatter.com/expert/scala/chris-marshall

Get a copy of Functional Programming in Scala from Manning written by some of the authors of scalaz.

I have a couple of small examples on my blog http://www.casualmiracles.com/blog/

I would say there is even easier places to start with scalaz than validation, which is the various enrichments on Option like ~foo which returns the value contained in the option or the 'zero' for the options's type (0 for numbers, empty string for String etc).

I forgot about a very detailed series of articles called Learning Scalaz at http://eed3si9n.com/

Answer (score 5):

As with any open-source project, the only really true and acceptable answer to "Why isn't their better documentation?" is "Because no one has written it yet.  You are free to volunteer."

(I honestly have no idea whether this answer will result in upvotes or downvotes.  Interesting experiment.)

Comment: I think the issue is, you can't write documentation for something you don't understand.